# Is save to use System.currentTimeMillis() after 2038?

Tags: java, android, year2038

The Year 2038 problem (also called Y2038 or Unix Y2K) relates to representing time in many digital systems as the number of seconds passed since 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 and storing it as a signed 32-bit integer. Such implementations cannot encode times after 03:14:07 UTC on 19 January 2038. Just like the Y2K problem, the Year 2038 problem is caused by insufficient capacity of the chosen data type.

[(source Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)

I tried to search how this affect Android and its applications. But I didn´t find any clear answer about this. Therefore I would like to ask here:

**Can we expect any problems in future (in 2038 and later), if our programs will use System.currentTimeMillis() method?**

**Are they any dangerous method we should avoid?**

Comment: It uses the operating system's clock, so mostly depends on the operating system. Consider it returs a `long`, so it should be able to go well beyond 2038

Comment: Yes. As you can see in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()), it returns a `long`, not an `int`.  The 2038 problem relates to 32-bit signed integers measuring time in seconds. `currentTimeMillis` uses a 64-bit signed integer measuring time in milliseconds. Unless the underlying source of information is invalid, the Java part of this isn't a problem.

Answer (score 11):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` returns a long, a 64 bit integer, so you'll be safe until [the year 292278994](https://ideone.com/Im9thL).

Luckily, we'll all be dead by then.

Comment: Nice answer, mainly last part :)